# Skyrim bug. Water textures flickering, Screen stuttering black, and Animals flying into the sky

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods

I have been playing skyrim for quite a while now. All of the sudden my games physics and textures are going out of their minds. I have my fps limited to 60 and vysnc is turned on. I would really appreciate some help.

My mod list:

```
Skyrim.esm
Update.esm
Dragonborn.esm
HearthFires.esm
Dawnguard.esm
ClimatesOfTamriel.esm
Dawnguard - Textures.esm
HearthFires - Textures.esm
Dragonborn - Textures.esm
Unofficial Skyrim Patch.esp
RaceCompatibility.esm
hdtHighHeel.esm
JSwords.esm
SkyUI.esp
AesirArmor.esp
Alternate Start - Live Another Life.esp
AmazingFollowerTweaks.esp
Bijin Warmaidens.esp
Blaze Of Eventide.esp
Colorful_Magic.esp
Donyaakin.esp
EdhildilsWitchDoctor.esp
Extended UI.esp
FNIS.esp
HelmetToggle2.02b.esp
Holidays.esp
Honorus.esp
NeoHorus.esp
BluePalaceCourtyard_-_Copy.esp
Hothtrooper44_Armor_Ecksstra.esp
Inconsequential NPCs.esp
Hothtrooper44_ArmorCompilation.esp
Immersive Citizens - AI Overhaul.esp
JKs Markarth.esp
JKs Riften.esp
JKs Whiterun.esp
JKs Windhelm.esp
KS Hairdo's.esp
LocalizedGuildJobs.esp
RaceChanger.esp
Luna.esp
Mars.esp
BP2Meeko.esp
AHZmoreHUD.esp
OBIS.esp
OBISDB.esp
RaceMenu.esp
RaceMenuPlugin.esp
DemonRaceWIP -No Tail.esp
Owning Houses Without Being a Thane.esp
Phenderix's Magic Evolved.esp
Headtracking.esp
dD - Realistic Ragdoll Force - Realistic.esp
KrittaKitty_horses_uniqueFrost.esp
RROctavia.esp
sjel blad castle.esp
Sulfuras The Reclaimed Hand - Johnskyrim.esp
Skyrim Unadoption Mod.esp
runesword stormbringer.esp
Spells_adding_removing_perk_points_Dexan1005.esp
Sweet&Sexy Lingerie.esp
zzArmormashups.esp
vwrNeckSeamFix.esp
TheEyesOfBeauty.esp
ZigurdzDemon.esp
SFO - Dragonborn.esp
Skyrim Flora Overhaul.esp
DemonRaceWIP.esp
SantaRobes.esp
UIExtensions.esp
AddItemMenu.esp
Sol.esp
Terra.esp
Venus.esp
Vindicator.esp
creatures.esp
merchant gold increase.esp
merchants revamped whiterun.esp
topkek.esp
wildlife_overhaul.esp
winterhold_improvements.esp
zuzugs monster mod madness.esp
colored_dragonscale_v1.esp
dr_bandolier.esp
more enemies.esp
stranger_danger.esp
windstadmine.esp
mxaor.esp
betterinns.esp
betterwinterhold.esp
bettermarkarthexterieur.esp
marchanditinerant.esp
bettercitiesjarlshouses.esp
bettercitiesnewfarm.esp
betterfire.esp
bettercitiesdocksolitude.esp
betterravenrock.esp
bettercitiesmorebees.esp
RatKing.esp
RealisticWaterTwo - Dawnguard.esp
RealisticWaterTwo - Waves - Dawnguard.esp
RealisticWaterTwo.esp
RealisticWaterTwo - Dragonborn.esp
RealisticWaterTwo - Legendary.esp
RealisticWaterTwo - Waves.esp
Alduin's son.esp
BlackDragon.esp
dD-No Spinning Death Animation Merged.esp
Guard Dialogue Overhaul.esp
Auto Unequip Ammo.esp
Inigo.esp
WindstadCellarFullyUpgraded.esp
Weightless Ores, Ingots, Firewood and Coal.esp
A Simple Marriage Mod.esp
Elemental Destruction.esp
Water Destruction.esp
Wind Destruction.esp
LostGrimoire.esp
Ordinator - Perks of Skyrim.esp
dD - Enhanced Blood Main.esp
dD-Dragonborn-Dawnguard-EBT Patch.esp
dD-Reduced Splatter Size.esp
dD-Reduced Wound Size.esp
AwpSylvanas.esp
ABT - Faster Arrows Improved +75%.esp
ABT - Faster Bolts Improved +50%.esp
ABT - Increased Bolts Damage (Vanilla) +100%.esp
ABT - Increased Progressive Damage (Vanilla) +100%.esp
ABT - Loot Arrows +25%.esp
ABT - Merchants Arrows +25%.esp
ABT - Recover +50% Arrows and Bolts.esp
Realistic Lighting Overhaul - Brighter Dungeons.esp
Realistic Lighting Overhaul - Dawnguard Interiors.esp
Realistic Lighting Overhaul - Dungeons.esp
Realistic Lighting Overhaul - Major City Exteriors.esp
Realistic Lighting Overhaul - Major City Interiors.esp
Realistic Lighting Overhaul - Minor Cities and Town
Interiors.esp
JaxonzRenamer.esp
```

Comment: Do you have any mods installed? Also a side note animals flying into the air is not unusual for Skyrim. Mammoths will also fall out of the sky.

Comment: Yea I have a lot of mods. Around 135.

Comment: I wouldn't call it skyrim if it has that much mods.

Comment: With 135 mods, it may be difficult to diagnose what the exact nature of your problem is. It may be conflicting mods, it could be a mod that isn't installed correctly, or it could be a myriad of other things. If you can provide more information, it may allow us to maybe narrow down the reasons.

Comment: I put my mod list if you wanna look at it at maybe decipher what mod could be causing this. If a mod is causing it at all.

Comment: Good lord that's a lot of mods. Testament to the community that it runs *at all*.

Comment: Not a lot compared to some other people

Comment: I read the title, didn't realise you had 130+ mods installed, and just thought "Yeah, that sounds about par for the course."

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem myself, exact same symptoms.
For me it was because i turned off v-sync, i suspect one of your mods does that.

But if your mod turns off V-sync its important to also use the FPS limiter mod from nexus (simple download and drag 2 files into skyrim folder).
I noticed that mod is not on the list.
Most programs that limit FPS dont actually solve the problem, but the FPS limiter from nexusmods does.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the base game with DLC and unofficial patches.  Either with your current save (do not SAVE if you do this), or start a new game.

It simply makes more sense for you to see if it is one of the mods than us, since we probably can't even recreate the bugs you are experience.

Once you determined it is one of your mods, disable a few at a time until things "work right" again, then isolate it from there.

Comment: disable half at a time in order for maximum efficiency!

Comment: Yea, you can effectively perform a binary search on it, should take about 8 times i think?

Comment: With so many mods, the chances are big that its 2 mods that are colliding in some way.